# How to use INDEX(MATCH()) with repeated values

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I need to create a report that checks the status of an order by looking for its ID in the database. The trouble is that if the order payment fails for some reason (most common is "credit card refused") and the buyer attempts to make a payment again, another register with the same ID is created.

I was using INDEX(MATCH()) for this and it works well when the payments go through on the first attempt, but if they fail, I get a wrong match because it will stop at the first match, and I need the last one.

I provided a sample sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10tDHL8UhgUqlGwtZohlrlD9sSOwz2ay23EwHOQN_1B4/edit#gid=0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX((IFNA(VLOOKUP(H3:H, SORT({A:B, ROW(A:A)}, 3, 0), 2, 0))))
```

[image]

[IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)